# The connection is open

Tags: c#, sql

A few months ago I made a test program for a project and everything worked fine there.
Now I am working on the program itself, so I copied the code from the test program and
changed the the names of the columns,buttons etc. so it would fit the current program.
When I try to add something into the database it does nothing on the first click, on the 
second pops up an error which says that the connection is open.. I really got no idea what's
the problem. I tried to check again if I made a mistake in a column name or the database name
but everything seems to be correct.
Note: I also have a function that show data from the database and it works without any problem.

```
private void InsertData()
{
    string NewCode = GenerateCode();
    string NewSentence = txtSentence.Text;
    string NewRow = NewRowNum();
    try
    {
        string AddData = "INSERT INTO ShopSentences (BinaryStrings,Sentence,RowNumber) VALUES (@NewBinaryString,@NewSentence,@NewRowNumber)";
        SqlCommand DataAdd = new SqlCommand(AddData, Connection);
        DataAdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewBinaryString", NewCode);
        DataAdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewNewSentence", NewSentence);
        DataAdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewRowNumber", NewRow);
        Connection.Open();
        DataAdd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Connection.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
}
//Checking the banary code in the last row
string GenerateCode()
{
    string RowNo = RowFind();
    int Row = int.Parse(RowNo);
    int Code = Row + 1;
    string Cd = Convert.ToString(Code, 2);
    int Ln = Cd.Trim().Length;
    if (Ln == 3)
    {
        Cd = "100" + Cd;
    }
    else if (Ln == 4)
    {
        Cd = "10" + Cd;
    }
    else if (Ln == 5)
    {
        Cd = "1" + Cd;
    }
    return Cd;
}
//Finding the last row
string RowFind()
{
    Connection.Open();
    string queryString = string.Format("SELECT * FROM ShopSentences");
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(queryString, Connection);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable("ShopSentences");
    sda.Fill(dt);
    Connection.Close();
    return dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["RowNumber"].ToString();
}
string NewRowNum()
{
    string Row = RowFind();
    int CalcRow = int.Parse(Row) + 1;
    Row = CalcRow.ToString();
    return Row;
}
```

The connection that appears to be open is the one in the string RowFind().

Here are the other related things to the database:

```
public partial class frmShop : Form
{
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection Connection;

    public frmShop()
    {
        string DatabaseConnection = WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Settings.Default.BinaryStringsDictionaryConnectionString1;
        Connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
        Connection.ConnectionString = DatabaseConnection;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void frmShop_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'binaryStringsDictionaryDataSet.ShopSentences' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.shopSentencesTableAdapter.Fill(this.binaryStringsDictionaryDataSet.ShopSentences);

    }

    private void GetSentence()
    {
        try
        {
            Connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader ReadSentence = null;
            Int32 BinaryInt = Int32.Parse(txtBinaryString.Text);
            string CommandString = "SELECT Sentence FROM ShopSentences WHERE BinaryStrings = @BinaryString";
            SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand(CommandString, Connection);
            Command.Parameters.Add("@BinaryString", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = BinaryInt;
            ReadSentence = Command.ExecuteReader();
            while (ReadSentence.Read())
            {
                txtSentence.Text = (ReadSentence["Sentence"].ToString());
                Fit = 1;
            }
            Connection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Before this `InsertData` method, maybe somewhere your `Connection` is alread open, and you try to open it againg? Use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `SqlConnection` objects.

Comment: At the very least you should encapsulate database access in a try block and move the Connection.Close() statement to a  finally block so that you close the connection even if there is an exception.

Comment: Post more code (include the Connection property and any other related stuff from the class).

Comment: I really don't want to use thing that I don't know so well...
I added more lines of the code @PeterKiss

Answer (score 1):

You are getting errors because you are reusing the same connection `Connection.Open();` several times.

Your method `InsertData()` is doing this 3 times in the same method.

You should create a new instance of the connection object and dispose it on your methods.

Using Statement are the way to go.

---

```
private void InsertData()
{
    using (var Connection = new SqlConnection(DatabaseConnection))
    {
        string NewCode = GenerateCode();
        string NewSentence = txtSentence.Text;
        string NewRow = NewRowNum();
        try
        {
            Connection.Open();
            string AddData = "INSERT INTO ShopSentences (BinaryStrings,Sentence,RowNumber) VALUES (@NewBinaryString,@NewSentence,@NewRowNumber)";
            SqlCommand DataAdd = new SqlCommand(AddData, Connection);
            DataAdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewBinaryString", NewCode);
            DataAdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewNewSentence", NewSentence);
            DataAdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewRowNumber", NewRow);
            DataAdd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            //Connection.Close(); no need to close
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

You can save one more connection if you store the row returned by `RowFind()`

```
string RowFind()
{
    using (var Connection = new SqlConnection(DatabaseConnection))
    {  
        Connection.Open();
        string queryString = string.Format("SELECT * FROM ShopSentences");
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(queryString, Connection);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("ShopSentences");
        sda.Fill(dt);
        //Connection.Close();
        return dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["RowNumber"].ToString();
    }
}
```

So you would connect once instead of twice:

```
var Row  = RowFind();
string NewCode = GenerateCode(Row);
string NewRow = NewRowNum(Row);
string NewSentence = txtSentence.Text;
```

---

Declare your connection string variable to a property so you can reuse it:

```
private string DatabaseConnection {get; set;}
```

Comment: `using` has been the way to go since .NET 1.0.

Comment: But how then it worked with the same code in a different program? I just did copy-paste with some changes.

Comment: Yes it can work, but it is bad practice to reuse a single connection globally.

Comment: @JohnSaunders strange I thought IDisposable were not available in older framework. is that wrong

Comment: @meda: yes, that's wrong. For instance, `Stream` has always implemented `IDisposable`. In fact, `IDisposable` is fairly fundamental to .NET: how else would you deterministically clean up unmanaged resources?

Comment: Okay I am trying to use the 'using' statement, but I don't understand how it should be written..

Comment: @user3144416 Its very easy, see example you wrap your code around the using block, and you dont close the connection.

Comment: That's what I tried to use but where do I get the connectionString from?

Comment: It depends, you can grab it from the app.config, In your program you store it as `DatabaseConnection`

Comment: Tried this one as well but is still says that it does not exist in this context.

Comment: Declare your connection string variable to a property so you can reuse it: `public string DatabaseConnection {get; set;}` then `DatabaseConnection = WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Settings.Default.BinaryStringsDictionaryConnectionString1;`

Comment: Now this thing appears: The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.

Comment: You can also put it everywhere you use it , right before the `using` add `string DatabaseConnection = WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Settings.Default.BinaryStringsDictionaryConnectionString1;` on top

Answer (score 0):

Instead using an instance level SqlConnection you should only provide a common factory for creating a connection:

```
public partial class frmShop : Form
{
    private string ConnectionString
    {
        get { return WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Settings.Default.BinaryStringsDictionaryConnectionString1; }
    }

    public frmShop()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private SqlConnection CreateConnection()
    {
        var conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();
        return conn;
    }

    private void frmShop_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'binaryStringsDictionaryDataSet.ShopSentences' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.shopSentencesTableAdapter.Fill(this.binaryStringsDictionaryDataSet.ShopSentences);
    }
    private void GetSentence()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var conn = CreateConnection())
            {
                var BinaryInt = int.Parse(txtBinaryString.Text);
                var commandString = "SELECT Sentence FROM ShopSentences WHERE BinaryStrings = @BinaryString";
                using (var Command = new SqlCommand(commandString, conn))
                {
                    Command.Parameters.Add("@BinaryString", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = BinaryInt;

                    using (var readSentence = Command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (readSentence.Read())
                        {
                            txtSentence.Text = (readSentence["Sentence"].ToString());
                            Fit = 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
         }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void InsertData()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var conn = CreateConnection())
            {
                var commandString = "INSERT INTO ShopSentences (BinaryStrings,Sentence,RowNumber) VALUES (@NewBinaryString,@NewSentence,@NewRowNumber)";
                using (var comm = new SqlCommand(commandString, conn))
                {
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewBinaryString", GenerateCode());
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewNewSentence", txtSentence.Text);
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewRowNumber", NewRowNum());

                    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
    //Checking the banary code in the last row
    string GenerateCode()
    {
        string RowNo = RowFind();
        int Row = int.Parse(RowNo);
        int Code = Row + 1;
        string Cd = Convert.ToString(Code, 2);
        int Ln = Cd.Trim().Length;
        if (Ln == 3)
        {
            Cd = "100" + Cd;
        }
        else if (Ln == 4)
        {
            Cd = "10" + Cd;
        }
        else if (Ln == 5)
        {
            Cd = "1" + Cd;
        }
        return Cd;
    }
    //Finding the last row
    string RowFind()
    {
        using (var conn = CreateConnection())
        {
            var commandString = "SELECT * FROM ShopSentences";
            using (var comm = new SqlCommand(commandString, conn))
            {
                using (var sda = new SqlDataAdapter(queryString, Connection))
                {
                    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable("ShopSentences"))
                    {
                        sda.Fill(dt);
                        return dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["RowNumber"].ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    string NewRowNum()
    {
        var Row = RowFind();
        var CalcRow = int.Parse(Row) + 1;
        return CalcRow.ToString();


}
}
```

But this is just the beginning you should not have any hard SQL dependency in your Form classes.

Answer (score 0):

When sharing same SqlConnection instance several times in your code, instead of directly opening the you can rather check the connection state first and then open it if not already opened. For example:

```
if(Connection.State!= ConnectionState.Open)
       Connection.Open();
```